# WP-Membersプラグインにて、ユーザーのメールアドレスが違う場合、登録できなくする方法

Tags: php, wordpress

WordPressでユーザ登録制のサイトを作っています。 ユーザ登録のプラグインとしては、「WP-Members」を利用しております。

メールアドレスが違うと通知が来ないのは普通だと思いますが、管理画面には登録が完了でできてしまいます。

以下のように実現したい

- メールアドレス違う場合→登録できない
- メールアドレスが正しい場合→登録完了ができる

メールアドレスが異なる場合に登録できないようにする方法は、カスタマイズが必要でしょうか。
カスタマイズ方法があれば教えてください。

それともWP-Membersプラグインは無料のプラグインだからこそ、そのようなことは不可でしょうか？　
管理画面で削除するしかない？

[image: WP Members管理画面のユーザー一覧]

メタキー　(コード）

[image: メタキー]

ユーザーが受信されているメールに「確認メール」をクリックされてない（またはメール通知が届かないのも含める）場合は、そのユーザーの一覧データに残させないカスタマイズ設定方法はありますか？

https://rocketgeek.com/plugins/wp-members/docs/
を参考したのですが、PHP知識がないため分かりません...ご教授いただけますと大変幸いです。

Comment: 達成したい目標は｢一覧に出てこないようにする」なのか「ログインできないようにする」なのかどちらでしょうか。前者っぽいように読み取れますが前者が不可能なのは自明なので。

Comment: @suzukis  
メールアドレス認証が確認完了するまで、ログインすることはできないので、なぜ一覧に出てくるのかそれを避けたいです。｢一覧に出てこないようにする」をしたいですが可能でしょうか?　　メールアドレスが認証された時点でユーザー一覧に出るというふうにして欲しいですが...

Answer (score 0):

PHP や WordPress の知識はありませんが、[Options](https://rocketgeek.com/plugins/wp-members/docs/plugin-settings/options/) のページで "Account Confirmation Link" が所望の機能に見えます。

> This feature sends a new user a confirmation link when they register. They will not be allowed to access the site until they have confirmed their account.
>
> If the user does not confirm the account, the link will expire in 24 hours and the user would have to register again.

Answer (score 0):

｢ユーザー登録｣→「メールアドレス確認」という流れだと、メールアドレス確認ができたら有効化すべきユーザーデータが保存されている必要がありますし、管理者が登録にまつわる問い合わせに対応できるようそれが参照できるようになっているのが一般的なニーズです。なので、あなたの希望とは根本的に相性が悪いわけです。

「中途半端なデータはいらない」というのを優先するのであれば、メールアドレス確認が先行する登録フローを持つプラグインを探すのが多分手っ取り早い解決策になります。ただし、利用者側のメリットになるかというとそうではないことに注意が必要です。

あと一応、見なかったことにするだけであれば一覧画面の検索条件をいじるという解決策がないでもありませんが、ソースコードの編集が必要だと思われるので難しいでしょう。